# Haskell Sieve of Eratosthenes with list of composites

Tags: list, haskell, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have to implement the classic problem of the Sieve of Eratosthenes in Haskell for a project. Rather than computing each prime I only have to compare numbers between lists. For instance I pass a list of potential primes (parameter 1) and a list of composites (list 2). `sieve [2..10] []` results with the list `[2,3,5,7]`.

I think I am very close and it compiles, but it appends every item to the prime list rather than throwing out the composites. My thinking was that it would take the list x of all numbers `2..10` or whatever and a list y of composites use `elem` to see if the head of list x is found in list y and if so append to list z and print. Thanks in advance!

Currently my code returns everything in the first list and refuses to sort. `sieve [2..10] []` results in `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

```
sieve ::[Int]->[Int]->[Int]
z = []
sieve [] [] = []
sieve x [] = x
sieve [] y = y
sieve xs ys = if ((elem (head xs)) ys) then (sieve (tail xs) ys)
    else ((head xs):z)
```

Comment: Your invocation of `sieve [2..10] []` pattern matches with the definition `sieve x [] = x`, so none of the other clauses for `sieve` are being used.

Comment: The program you show doesn't make much sense, first of all `sieve x []` will always be used, furthermore in you should check if an element is divisable by the other list. Finally you should make the call recursive, something you don't do with `head xs : z` since `z` is defined as the empty list.

Comment: no divisibility checks are to be performed in the sieve of Eratosthenes!!

Comment: @WillNess: then (a) why does [this implementation](http://en.literateprograms.org/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes_%28Haskell%29#A_first_look) uses divisibility checks, (b) if you add elements to `ys` for most applications, the elements will be smaller, so the sieve would allow all elements; and (3) this wiki article clearly states [divisibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Trial_division). You can indeed implement a version where composites are calculates for `ys`, but that will reduce the performance of the algorithm.

Comment: @CommuSoft (a) is not a sieve of Eratosthenes, it is a sieve of trial division. (b) didn't understand you, sorry. (c) yes, it says "It is often confused with the sieve of Eratosthenes" i.e. it is *not* the sieve of Eratosthenes, it is *confused* for it. If you haven's seen [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers) yet, maybe it will be an interesting read. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you call `sieve` is usually called `minus`, subtracting the second list from the first, *assuming* the both are ordered, increasing lists of numbers. then it is enough to compare just the two head elements, without any `elem` calls.

but it could still work, had you provided a proper definition for `z`. `z=[]` is just a placeholder, to make it compile (right?); it's not the right definition. it should have been:

```
sieve :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
-- z = []
sieve [] [] = []
sieve x [] = x
sieve [] y = y
sieve xs ys = if ((elem (head xs)) ys) then (sieve (tail xs) z)
    else ((head xs) : sieve (tail xs) ys )
      where
         z = ... -- need to remove (head xs) from ys
```

For the last comment's task, you could use e.g. [`delete`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:delete) function.

This still won't produce you a list of primes without the list of composites, so the initial call can *not* be with the second list empty (or else, you'd get the same first argument back, as you do, because of the `sieve x [] = x` equation):

```
primesAmong input = sieve input composites
```

But what are `composites`? Eratosthenes's answer is, *why, they are multiples of primes!* (and trial division says: *composites have other primes as their divisors*).

Given a prime, say 2, we just count: *2,4,6,...*; and for 3, say, it's *3,6,9,12,...*; to find its multiples. Let's write it down:

```
composites = mutliplesOf primes
mutliplesOf primes = [ mult | p <- primes, mult <- [...] ]
```

This doesn't quite fit: this `multiplesOf` needs an argument:

```
primes = primesAmong input
primesAmong input = sieve input (mutliplesOf primes)
```

We seem to be chasing our own tail here; we don't have `primes` yet; what can we use instead? Is there a harm in finding multiples of non-primes, as well as primes?

After you do have a running code, try to find a way to use `primes` after all.

Comment: Didn't end up needing the delete function but found a lot of problems with my base case and a few other things. only needed sieve [] y = []. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The program you show doesn't make much sense, first of all `sieve x []` will always be used, furthermore in you should check if an element is divisable by the other list. Finally you should make the call recursive, something you don't do with `head xs : z` since `z` is defined as the empty list.

Let's start with the base case: in case the left list is empty, regardless of the content of the second list, one returns the empty list. Since sieving nothing will result in nothing:

```
sieve [] _ = []
```

Next we look for the inductive case, with as pattern:

```
sieve (x:xs) ds = ...
```

Now we need to enumerate over the list of already found elements. From the moment `any` of the found elements can divide `x`, we know the number is not *(relative) prime*. This condition is formalized as:

```
(==) 0 . mod x :: Integral b => b -> Bool
```

Or to iterate over the list of `ds`:

```
any ((==) 0 . mod x) ds
```

In case such element exists, we simply skip the element, and call the inductive case with `sieve xs ds`.

In case there is no such element, we add it to the list of `ds` and emit it. The result is thus: `x : sieve xs (x:ds)`. The inductive case is thus:

```
sieve (x:xs) ds | any ((==) 0 . mod x) ds = sieve xs ds
                | otherwise = x : sieve xs (x:ds)
```

We can shorten this a bit by creating a specific variable for `sieve xs`:

```
sieve (x:xs) ds | any ((==) 0 . mod x) ds = rec ds
                | otherwise = x : rec (x:ds)
                where rec = sieve xs
```

The full function is thus:

```
sieve [] _ = []
sieve (x:xs) ds | any ((==) 0 . mod x) ds = rec ds
                | otherwise = x : rec (x:ds)
                where rec = sieve xs
```

You can boost the performance in two ways:

- Adding `x` at the end of `ds`. This is indeed a more expensive operation. But after a while you don't add numbers that often. It is interesting because in that case `ys` looks like `[2,3,5,7,11]` instead of `[11,7,5,3,2]`. Now the chances that a number is divisible by `2` (50%) is greater than a number being divisible by `11` (9.9%). It is better to try to try the test that will succeed most probable first.
- Furthermore you can end the check after the dividers you have reached the square root of the number to be tested: if a number is not divisible by a number smaller than such number, it is definitely not divisible by a number greater than the square root.

A more efficient approach is thus:

```
sieve [] _ = []
sieve (x:xs) ds | any ((==) 0 . mod x) $ takeWhile (\y -> y*y <= x) ds = rec ds
                | otherwise = x : rec (ds++[x])
                where rec = sieve xs
```

Comment: very good explanation - but I think the result will be in the wrong order (which might or might not be a problem for the OP) maybe you can fix that - also this is of course not the *sieve* but I think you know this already

Comment: @CarstenKönig: you mean the order of `ys`? Indeed by appending `x` at the end of `ys` (case 2), you can boost performance a bit since it is more likely a number to be diviseable by `2` than by `3`. But since the order of `ys` does not has an impact on *the result* of the check. If one calls `sieve [2..] []` the prime numbers are ordered.